# jQuery fading "back to top" link. Page load link visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrolltop

I am attempting to implement a "back to top" link that fades in on my page once a user has scrolled down the page a certain amount.

I have noticed that on some of my pages, the "back to top" link will flash on the page before hiding itself, but not on others. In an attempt to track down the cause of the "link flash" I have created a JS fiddle for you to view my coding, and hopefully find what is causing the inconsistency. The JS fiddle itself seems to be working properly, but that might just be because it is in a fiddle. Would there maybe be a line of code I could add to ensure the link is hidden on load?

Thanks for taking the time to look at this. It is greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/uLUWV/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
Test Content
</div>    
<p id="back-top"><a href="#top"><span>Go To Top</span></a></p>
```

CSS

```
#back-top {position: fixed; display:none; bottom:10px; left:10px; width:83px;}
#back-top a {width: 83px; display: block;}
#back-top span {width: 83px; height: 94px; display: block; background-color:red;}

.container {height:4000px;}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // hide #back-top first
    $("#back-top").hide();

    // fade in #back-top
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
                $('#back-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#back-top a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Seems fine in FF 21.0 WinXP

Comment: seems fine also in Chrome 27 on Linux.

Comment: OP said it work on fiddle but not on his site, so of course it work fine. @Alex Ritter, can you post your not working page?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Sure: http://temp.yandasmusic.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spotted your problem.

You need to put in your CSS `#back-top{display : none}`.

One is there, but it is getting overrided by your media-queries. You need a more specifique selector only for the display.

Add this line in `skin.css` and it should correct the bug :

```
p#back-top{display : none}
```

Check after if your media-queries still work. If no, you'll have to be more specific in your queries too.

Right now, your button is being hided by `.hide()`. So once you can hide the button by CSS, you will be able to remove this line.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code below and it worked without problems

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html> 
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                // hide #back-top first
                $("#back-top").hide();

                // fade in #back-top
                $(function () {
                    $(window).scroll(function () {
                        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
                            $('#back-top').fadeIn();
                        } else {
                            $('#back-top').fadeOut();
                        }
                    });

                    // scroll body to 0px on click
                    $('#back-top a').click(function () {
                        $('body,html').animate({
                            scrollTop: 0
                        }, 800);
                        return false;
                    });
                });

            });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #back-top {position: fixed; display:none; bottom:10px; left:10px; width:83px;}
    #back-top span {width: 83px; height: 94px; display: block; background-color:red;}

    .container {height:4000px;}

#back-top a {width: 83px; display: block;color: white;}
#back-top a:active {
color: white;
}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    Test Content
    </div>    
    <p id="back-top"><a href="#top"><span>Go To Top</span></a></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This code works in your browser?

Comment: It does work on most pages, which is the strange thing about it. There are a few pages in which the link flashes every time. You can view this at http://temp.yandasmusic.com